# Problem when importing images. Please help!

Tags: graphics

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{vntex}
%\usepackage[english,vietnam]{babel}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage{a4wide,amssymb,epsfig,latexsym,array,hhline,fancyhdr}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{multicol,longtable,amscd}
\usepackage{diagbox}%Make diagonal lines in tables
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{alltt}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}% For highlighting paragraph backgrounds
\usepackage{caption,subcaption}

\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage[lined,boxed,commentsnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{graphicx}                           % Standard graphics package
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx, caption}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,snakes,backgrounds}
\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{urlcolor=blue,linkcolor=black,citecolor=black,colorlinks=true} 
%\usepackage{pstcol}                                % PSTricks with the standard color package

\newtheorem{theorem}{{\bf Định lý}}
\newtheorem{property}{{\bf Tính chất}}
\newtheorem{proposition}{{\bf Mệnh đề}}
\newtheorem{corollary}[proposition]{{\bf Hệ quả}}
\newtheorem{lemma}[proposition]{{\bf Bổ đề}}


%\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\setlength{\headheight}{40pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{} % clear all header fields
\fancyhead[L]{
 \begin{tabular}{rl}
    \begin{picture}(25,15)(0,0)
    \put(0,-8){\includegraphics[width=8mm, height=8mm]{Images/hcmut.png}}
    %\put(0,-8){\epsfig{width=10mm,figure=hcmut.eps}}
   \end{picture}&
    %\includegraphics[width=8mm, height=8mm]{hcmut.png} & %
    \begin{tabular}{l}
        \textbf{\bf \ttfamily Trường Đại Học Bách Khoa Tp.Hồ Chí Minh}\\
        \textbf{\bf \ttfamily Khoa Khoa Học và Kỹ Thuật Máy Tính}
    \end{tabular}   
 \end{tabular}
}
\fancyhead[R]{
    \begin{tabular}{l}
        \tiny \bf \\
        \tiny \bf 
    \end{tabular}  }
\fancyfoot{} % clear all footer fields
\fancyfoot[L]{\scriptsize \ttfamily Bài tập lớn môn Cấu trúc Rời rạc cho KHMT (CO1007) - Niên khóa 2015-2016}
\fancyfoot[R]{\scriptsize \ttfamily Trang {\thepage}/\pageref{LastPage}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.3pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.3pt}


%%%
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\makeatletter
\newcounter {subsubsubsection}[subsubsection]
\renewcommand\thesubsubsubsection{\thesubsubsection .\@alph\c@subsubsubsection}
\newcommand\subsubsubsection{\@startsection{subsubsubsection}{4}{\z@}%
                                     {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                     {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
                                     {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\newcommand*\l@subsubsubsection{\@dottedtocline{3}{10.0em}{4.1em}}
\newcommand*{\subsubsubsectionmark}[1]{}
\makeatother

\everymath{\color{blue}}%make in-line maths symbols blue to read/check easily

\sloppy
\captionsetup[figure]{labelfont={small,bf},textfont={small,it},belowskip=-1pt,aboveskip=-9pt}
%space remove between caption, figure, and text
\captionsetup[table]{labelfont={small,bf},textfont={small,it},belowskip=-1pt,aboveskip=7pt}
%space remove between caption, table, and text

%\floatplacement{figure}{H}%forced here float placement automatically for figures
%\floatplacement{table}{H}%forced here float placement automatically for table
%the following settings (11 lines) are to remove white space before or after the figures and tables
%\setcounter{topnumber}{2}
%\setcounter{bottomnumber}{2}
%\setcounter{totalnumber}{4}
%\renewcommand{\topfraction}{0.85}
%\renewcommand{\bottomfraction}{0.85}
%\renewcommand{\textfraction}{0.15}
%\renewcommand{\floatpagefraction}{0.8}
%\renewcommand{\textfraction}{0.1}
\setlength{\floatsep}{5pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}
\setlength{\textfloatsep}{5pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}
\setlength{\intextsep}{10pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}
ĐẠI HỌC QUỐC GIA THÀNH PHỐ HỒ CHÍ MINH \\
TRƯỜNG ĐẠI HỌC BÁCH KHOA \\
KHOA KHOA HỌC - KỸ THUẬT MÁY TÍNH 
\end{center}

\vspace{1cm}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=3cm]{Images/hcmut.png}
\end{center}
\end{figure}

\vspace{1cm}


\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{c}
\multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{{\Large CẤU TRÚC RỜI RẠC CHO KHMT (CO1007)}}}\\
~~\\
\hline
\\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{{\Large Nhóm: 23 ---- Bài tập lớn}}}\\
\\
\textbf{{\Huge Thống kê mô tả và}} \\
\textbf{{\Huge Xác suất rời rạc với R}}\\
\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\vspace{1.5cm}

\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabular}{rrl}
\hspace{5 cm} & GVHD: & Nguyễn An Khương\\
\hspace{5 cm} &  & Huỳnh Tường Nguyên\\

& SV thực hiện: & Phan Trần Thái Sơn -- 1512853 \\
& & Lý Minh Thịnh -- 1513254 \\
& & Nguyễn Lương Phúc Vinh -- 1514063 \\
& & Huỳnh Minh Thịnh -- 1513245 \\
& & Mai Lê Thông -- 1513293 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\vspace{1.5cm}
\begin{center}
{\footnotesize Tp. Hồ Chí Minh, Tháng .../2015}
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}

%\thispagestyle{empty}

\newpage
\tableofcontents
\newpage

Bài báo cáo này trình bày lời giải một số bài toán về thống kê mô tả và mộ số bài toán liên quan đến các mô hình xác suất rời rạc có sử dụng R.

Trong phần đầu, chúng tôi nhắc lại một số kiến thức và kết quả cơ bản về thống kê mô tả, và các mô hình xác suất rời rạc thông dụng, cùng với một số hàm R thông dụng mà chúng tôi sử dụng để tính toán kết quả trong các lời giải của các bài toán trong Phần \ref{bai_tap}.

Đối với mỗi bài toán Phần \ref{bai_tap}, trước hết chúng tôi trình bày lời giải truyền thống, bằng cách dùng các công thức và kết quả đã được trình bày trong Phần~\ref{chuan_bi}. Sau đó chúng tôi tính toán lại kết quả bằng các hàm R. Các biểu đồ (nếu có) cũng sẽ được vẽ bằng R và nhúng vào LaTeX.

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\section{Kiến thức và kết quả chuẩn bị}\label{chuan_bi}
\subsection{Tổng quan về R} 

Trong phần này chúng tôi giới thiệu tóm lược về ngôn ngữ R và ứng dụng của nó trong xác suất và thống kê.

R là ngôn ngữ lâp trình thống kê sáng lập bởi nhóm tác giả "R Development Core Team" tại đại học đại học Auckland, do Ross Ihaka và Robert Gentleman khởi xướng và phát triển từ ngôn ngữ lập trình thống kê S. Do đặc trưng của phần mềm mã nguồn mở, R nhận được đóng góp xây dựng từ khắp các nơi trong cộng đồng khoa học.

Ngôn ngữ R đã trở thành một tiêu chuẩn trên thực tế (de facto) giữa các nhà thống kê cho thấy sự phát triển của phần mềm thống kê, và được sử dụng rộng rãi để phát triển phần mềm thống kê và phân tích dữ liệu.

\subsection{Thống kê mô tả}
Trong phần này chúng tôi tóm lược lại một số kiến thức căn bản về thống kê mô tả như các dạng dữ liệu, mẫu ngẫu nhiên, các loại biểu đồ, đồ thị, và các số đặc trưng của mẫu.

\subsubsection{Các loại dữ liệu}
Có hai loại dữ liệu chủ yếu là dữ liệu định tính và dữ liệu định lượng.\\
Trong dữ liệu định lượng lại phân ra hai loại khác là: dữ liệu đinh lượng rời rạc và dữ liệu định lượng liên tục
\subsubsection{Tổng thể và mẫu}
\subsubsection*{Tổng thể}
\begin{itemize}
  \item Khi nghiên cứu về một vấn đề người ta thường khảo sát trên một dấu hiệu nào đó. Các dấu hiệu này thể hiện trên nhiều phần tử. Tập hợp các phần tử đó được gọi là \textit{Tổng thể}.\\
  \item \textbf{Chú ý:} Các khái niệm và ký hiệu:

1. $N$: số phần tử của tổng thể, hay còn gọi là kích thước của tổng thể

2. $X^{*}$: dấu hiệu mà ta khảo sát

3. $x_{i}(i=\bar{1,k})$: giá trị của dấu hiệu $X^{*}$ đo được trên phần tử của tổng thể ($x_{i}$ là thông tin mà ta quan tâm, còn các phần tử của tổng thể là vật mang thông tin).

4. $N_{i}(i=\bar{1,k})$: tần số của $x_{i}$ (số phần tử có chung giá trị $x_{i}$)

5. $p_{i}=\frac{N_{i}}{N}$: tần suất của $x_{i}$\\
  \item Các đặc trưng của tổng thể

1. Trung bình của dấu hiệu $X^{*}$ (trung bình của tổng thể): $m=\sum_{i=1}^{k}x_{i}p_{i}$.

2. Phương sai của dấu hiệu $X^{*}$ (phương sai của tổng thể): $\sigma^{2}=\sum_{i=1}^{k}(x_{i}-m)^{2}p_{i}$

3. Độ lệch chuẩn của dấu hiệu $X^{*}$ (độ lệch chuẩn của tổng thể): $\sigma=\sqrt{\sigma^{2}}=\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{k}(x_{i}-m)^{2}p_{i}}$
\end{itemize}
\subsubsection*{Mẫu}
\begin{itemize}

  \item Từ tổng thể lấy ra n phần tử và đo lường dấu hiệu $X^{*}$ trên chúng. Khi đó n phần tử này lập nên một \textit{mẫu}. Số phần tử của mẫu được gọi là kích thước của mẫu.

  \item Mẫu đại diện cho tổng thể, các số đặc trưng của tổng thể cũng được tính trên mẫu.

  \item Mẫu ngẫu nhiên là mẫu được lựa chọn bằng phương pháp mà khả năng được chọn vào tổng thể mẫu của tất cả các đơn vị của tổng thể đều như nhau.
\end{itemize}

\subsubsection{Các loại biểu đồ và đồ thị thông dụng}
\begin{itemize}
  \item Biểu đồ cột

  \item Biểu đồ tròn

  \item Biểu đồ Hộp và Râu

  \item Biểu đồ tứ phân vị

  \item Biểu đồ Thân và Lá

\end{itemize}

\subsubsection{Phân tích mô tả các giá trị mẫu}
Trong mục này, chúng tôi trình bày một số bước đầu tiên để phân tích dữ liệu thu thập được trong quá trình lấy mẫu. Một cách để mô tả một phân phối các giá trị mẫu, đặc biệt hữu ích trong các mẫu lớn, là xây dựng một phân phối tần số (tần suất) của các giá trị mẫu. \\
Chúng tôi sẽ trình bày cách xây dựng một phân phối tần số (tần suất) dành cho hai loại biến: (i)biến \textbf{rời rạc} và (ii)biến \textbf{liên tục}.

\subsubsubsection{Phân phối tần số (tần suất) của biến ngẫu nhiên rời rạc}
Xét một biến ngẫu nhiên rời rạc $X$, $X$ chỉ có thể nhận những giá trị $x_{1},x_{2},...,x_{k}$ với $x_{1}<x_{2}<...<x_{k}$. Giả sử chúng ta đã thực hiện $n$ quan sát khác nhau trên $X$. Tần số của $x_{i}(i=1,...,k)$ là xác định với những quan sát có giá trị $x_{i}$. Chúng ta biểu diễn tần số của $x_{i}$ bằng $f_{i}$. Ta được:\\

\centerline{$\sum_{i=1}^{k}f_{i}=f_{1}+f_{2}+...+f_{k}=n$.}\\
\begin{flushleft}
Tập các cặp có thứ tự:
\end{flushleft}
\centerline{$\left \{ (x_{1},f_{1}),(x_{2},f_{2}),...,(x_{k},f_{k}) \right \}$}

\begin{flushleft}
tạo thành phân phối tần số của X.

Đôi khi để thể hiện tỷ lệ giữa các tần số $p_{i}$, ta có thể biểu diễn:

\end{flushleft}

\begin{flushleft}
\centerline{$p_{i}=f_{i}/n$  $(i=1,...,k)$}
\end{flushleft}

\subsubsubsection{Phân phối tần số (tần suất) của biến ngẫu nhiên liên tục}
Với biến ngẫu nhiên liên tục, chúng ta phân chia phạm vi có thể của sự biến đổi của các biến quan sát thành $k$ khoảng con. Nói một cách tổng quát, nếu phạm vi có thể của $X$ là giữa $L$ và $H$, ta xác định những số $b_{0},b_{1},b_{2},...,b_{k}$ với $L=b_{0}<b_{1}<b_{2}<...<b_{k-1}<b_{k}=H$. Các giá trị $b_{0},b_{1},b_{2},...,b_{k}$ gọi là các giới hạn của $k$ khoảng con. Sau đó ta phân loại các giá trị $X$ thành các khoảng $(b_{i-1},b_{i})$ nếu $b_{i-1}<X\leq b_{i}(i=1,...,k)$.(Nếu $X=b_{0}$, ta cho nó là khoảng con đầu tiên.)

\subsection{Xác suất cơ bản}
Trong phần này chúng tôi nhắc lại một số khái niệm cơ bản về xác suất rời rạc.
\begin{itemize}
\item \textbf{Tính ngẫu nhiên} là ngược lại với tính có xác định trước trong lý thuyết xác suất.
\item \textbf{Phép thử} là một quy trình mà sinh ra kết quả thuộc tập chứa tất cả các kết quả khả thi một cách ngẫu nhiên.
\item \textbf{Không gian mẫu} là tập tất cả các kết quả khả thi.
\item \textbf{Biến cố} là một tập con của không gian mẫu.
\item \textbf{Xác suất} của một biến cố là khả năng xảy ra biến cố đó, được đánh giá dưới dạng một số thực nằm giữa 0 và 1.
\end{itemize}

\subsection{Biến ngẫu nhiên rời rạc}
Trong phần này chúng tôi trình bày lại một số khái niệm và kết quả quan trọng về các biến ngẫu nhiên rời rạc, cùng với các số đặc trưng của chúng như: kỳ vọng, phương sai, mode, trung vị, moment cấp cao, mức phân vị,... mà sẽ được dùng để giải các bài toán trong phần sau.

Đối với mỗi đặc trưng số, chúng tôi nêu ra các hàm R để tính toán liên quan đến chúng .
\subsubsection{Khái niệm biến ngẫu nhiên rời rạc và ví dụ}
\begin{itemize}
  \item\textbf{Biến ngẫu nhiên rời rạc} là biến nhận giá trị bằng số thuộc một tập hữu hạn nào đó và giá trị ấy ngẫu nhiên, không dự đoán trước được.

  \item\textbf{Ví dụ}: Gọi X là số vụ vi phạm luật giao thông trên đường Đặng Văn Bi vào sáng thứ Hai hàng tuần. X là biến ngẫu nhiên rời rạc.
\end{itemize}
\subsubsection{Phân phối xác suất của biến ngẫu nhiên rời rạc}
\begin{itemize}
  \item Xét biến ngẫu nhiên rời rạc X có thể nhận các giá trị $0, 1, 2,..., n$.
  \item \textbf{Phân phối xác suất} của X có thể được mô tả bằng các \textbf{xác suất điểm} $f_{X}(x)=p(X=x)$
  \item hoặc \textbf{hàm phân phối tích lũy} $F(x)=p(X \leq x)$
\end{itemize}
\subsubsection{Các đặc trưng số quan trọng của của biến ngẫu nhiên rời rạc}
\begin{itemize}
  \item\textbf{Giá trị kỳ vọng}:\\
  $\mu = E(X)=\sum x . p(X=x).$ 
  \item\textbf{Phương sai}:\\
  $\sigma^{2} = V(X)=\sum (x-E(X))^{2}.p(X=x).$
  \item\textbf{Độ lệch chuẩn}:\\
  $\sigma = SD(X)=\sqrt{V(X)}.$
\end{itemize}
\subsection{Một vài mô hình xác suất rời rạc quen thuộc}
Trong phần này chúng tôi nêu ra các mô hình cụ thể mà chúng tôi sử dụng để giải các bài toán trong phần sau. Đối với mỗi mô hình chúng tôi nêu ra tường mình các đặc trưng số quan trọng của chúng, cũng như các hàm R để tính toán các đặc trưng số này
\subsubsection{Mô hình nhị thức}
\begin{itemize}
  \item $n$ = số phép thử
  \item $p$ = xác suất thành công ($q=1-p$ = xác suất thất bại)
  \item $X$ = số lần thành công trong $n$ lần thử
  \item Ta có: $p(X=x)=\binom{n}{x}p^{x}q^{n-x}.$
  \item Giá trị kỳ vọng: $\mu=np$
  \item Độ lệch chuẩn: $\sigma=\sqrt{npq}$.
\end{itemize}

\subsubsection{Mô hình hình học}
\begin{itemize}
  \item $p$ = xác suất thành công ($q=1-p$ = xác suất thất bại)
  \item $X$ = số phép thử cho tới khi thành công lần đầu tiên 
  \item Ta có: $p(X=x)=q^{x-1}p$
  \item Giá trị kỳ vọng: $\mu=\frac{1}{b}$
  \item Độ lệch chuẩn: $\sigma=\sqrt{\frac{q}{p^{2}}}$
\end{itemize}

\subsubsection{Mô hình Poisson}
\begin{itemize}
  \item Mô hình xác suất Poisson để xấp xỉ mô hình nhị thức khi xác suất thành công $p$ là rất nhỏ, và số phép thử $n$ là rất lớn.
  \item Thông số cho mô hình Poisson là $\lambda$. Để xấp xỉ mô hình nhị thức, chỉ cần cho trị trung bình của nó là: $\lambda=np$
  \item Mô hình Poisson hữu dụng khi xem xét các biến cố hiếm nhưng có hậu quả lớn.
  \item $\lambda$ = số lần trung bình của thành công = $np$
  \item $X$ = số lần thành công
  \item Ta có $P(X=x)=\frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^{x}}{x!}$
  \item Giá trị kỳ vọng: $\mu = \lambda$
  \item Độ lệch chuẩn: $\sigma=\sqrt{\lambda}$
\end{itemize}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\section{Một số bài toán minh họa}\label{bai_tap}
Trong phần này chúng tôi sẽ trình bày lời giải tường minh của một số bài toán đã được giao trong đề bài của nhóm. Các tính toán bằng R để kiểm tra kết quả và các biểu đồ minh họa cũng sẽ được nêu rõ.
    \subsection{Bài toán 1} Trong gói $mistat$, tập tin \textbf{FILMSP.csv} chứa dữ liệu được thu thập từ 217 cuộn phim. Dữ liệu chứa tốc độ phim được đo trong một phòng đặc biệt.\\
    Các lệnh R sau sẽ cài đặt các gói $mistat$, đọc tập dữ liệu $FILMSP$ về tốc độ phim đo được, và hiển thị chúng trên màn hình máy tính.\\
    \begin{mdframed}[hidealllines=true,backgroundcolor=magenta!10]
\begin{alltt}
\textit{
> # Sau dấu này là một comment
> install.packages("mistat",          # Cài đặt gói mistat
                   dependencies=TRUE) # và tất cả các gói có liên quan đến nó
> library(mistat) # Gọi ra các tập dữ liệu và hàm có trong gói
> data(FILMSP)     # Gọi ra tập dữ liệu về tốc độ phim đo được
> help(FILMSP)     # Đọc tất cả các thông tin hỗ trợ về tập dữ liệu FILMSP
> FILMSP           # Đưa ra các số liệu FILSMP trên màn hình máy tính
}
\end{alltt}
\end{mdframed}

\begin{enumerate}
\item Hãy trích xuất ra tốc độ phim đo được của 30 cuộn phim đầu tiên trong số 217 cuộn phim trong tập dữ liệu kể từ cuộn phim thứ $123$?
\item Tính tần số, tần suất và tần suất tích lũy của mẫu 30 cuộn phim trên.
\item Vẽ biểu đồ tần số của mẫu 30 cuộn phim trên.
\item Vẽ biểu đồ tần suất của mẫu 30 cuộn phim trên.
\item Vẽ biểu đồ tần suất tích lũy của mẫu 30 cuộn phim trên.
\item Tính tốc độ trung bình, trung vị mẫu, cực đại mẫu, cực tiểu mẫu của mẫu 30 cuộn phim trên.
\item Hãy đo mức độ phân tán của tốc độ phim (xung quanh giá trị trung bình) của 30 cuộn phim trên.
\item Tính độ méo lệch (skewness), và độ nhọn (kurtosis) của dữ liệu trong 30 cuộn phim trên.
\item Tính tứ phân vị (quartile) thứ nhất ($Q_{1}$) và thứ ba ($Q_{3}$)  của mẫu 30 cuộn phim trên.
\item Tính phân vị thứ $77\%$, phân vị thứ $23\%$, phân vị thứ $61,5\%$ và $38,5\%$ của mẫu 30 cuộn phim trên.
    \end{enumerate}

\begin{proof}[\textbf{\textit{Lời giải}}]
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item Trong R ta có thể trích xuất ra tốc độ phim đo được của 30 cuộn phim đầu tiên trong số 217 cuộn phim trong tập dữ liệu kể từ cuộn phim thứ 123 bằng lệnh:\\
    \begin{mdframed}[hidealllines=true,backgroundcolor=magenta!10]
\begin{alltt}
    \textit{
> FILMSP[123:152]
}
\end{alltt}
    \end{mdframed}
    Số liệu hiện ra trên màn hình máy tính là như sau:
    \begin{mdframed}[hidealllines=true,backgroundcolor=magenta!10]
\begin{alltt}
    \textit{
[1] 102 103 107 104 108 104 104 101 106 105 106  89  92 105 103 101 103\\
109 107

[20] 107 109  97  90  93  94 105 106 107 103 100
}
\end{alltt}
    \end{mdframed} 
    \item Tần số, tần suất và tần suất tích lũy của mẫu 30 cuộn phim trên được hiển thị trong Bảng \ref{T:speed freq-distribution} sau đây.
    \begin{table}[h]  
\begin{center} \caption{Tần suất của mẫu 30 cuộn phim trên}  \label{T:speed freq-distribution}
\begin{tabular}{cccc}  
\toprule[2pt]
\multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Tốc độ phim}}    & \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Tần số} $f_i$}   &  \textbf{Tần suất}&   \textbf{Tần suất tích lũy}                           \\
    &       &   $p_i=f_i/n$ & $P_i=\sum_{k=0}^ip_i$\\
\hline
89  & 1 & 0.03  & .50 \\
90  & 1 & 0.03  & .77\\
92  & 1 & 0.03  & .87 \\
93  & 1 & 0.03  & .97\\
94  & 1 & 0.03  & .97\\
97  & 1 & 0.03  & 1.00   \\ 
100 & 1 & 0.03  & 0   \\
101 & 2 & 0.07  & 0   \\
102 & 1 & 0.03  & 0   \\
103 & 4 & 0.13  & 0   \\
104 & 3 & 0.10  & 0   \\
105 & 3 & 0.10  & 0   \\
106 & 3 & 0.10  & 0   \\
107 & 4 & 0.13  & 0   \\
108 & 1 & 0.03  & 0   \\
109 & 2 & 0.07  & 0   \\
\hline
\textbf{Tổng} &  $n=30$ &  $0.97$ & \\
  \bottomrule[2pt]
\end{tabular}  
\end{center}
\end{table}

Trong R ta có thể tạo bảng trên như sau. 

\begin{mdframed}[hidealllines=true,backgroundcolor=magenta!10]
\begin{alltt}
\textit{
> X <- factor(FILMSP[123:152])
> X <- table(X)
> X <- factor(FILMSP[123:152])
> X <- table(X)
> cbind("Tan so"=X, "Tan suat"=X/sum(X), "Tan suat tich luy"=cumsum(X
\\/sum(X)))

  Tan so   Tan suat Tan suat tich luy
89       1 0.03333333        0.03333333
90       1 0.03333333        0.06666667
92       1 0.03333333        0.10000000
93       1 0.03333333        0.13333333
94       1 0.03333333        0.16666667
97       1 0.03333333        0.20000000
100      1 0.03333333        0.23333333
101      2 0.06666667        0.30000000
102      1 0.03333333        0.33333333
103      4 0.13333333        0.46666667
104      3 0.10000000        0.56666667
105      3 0.10000000        0.66666667
106      3 0.10000000        0.76666667
107      4 0.13333333        0.90000000
108      1 0.03333333        0.93333333
109      2 0.06666667        1.00000000
}
\end{alltt}
\end{mdframed}

\item Vẽ biểu đồ tần số của tốc độ trên 30 cuộn phim gốm: Trong R ta thực hiện
\begin{mdframed}[hidealllines=true,backgroundcolor=magenta!10]
\begin{alltt}
\textit{
>  barplot(X, width=1, space=1, col="gray", ylab="Tan so", xlab="Toc do phim")
}
\end{alltt}
\end{mdframed}
để thu được biểu đồ tần số như trong Hình~\ref{Fig:Frequency} sau.
\begin{figure}[h]\caption{Biểu đồ cột về số nhược điểm trên tấm gốm} \label{Fig:Frequency}
    \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.8]{Images/Frequency.png}
    \end{center}
\end{figure}

\item Vẽ biểu đồ tần suất của số lượng lỗi trên 30 tấm gốm: Trong R ta thực hiện
\begin{mdframed}[hidealllines=true,backgroundcolor=magenta!10]
\begin{alltt}
\textit{
>  barplot(X/sum(X), width=1, space=1, col="gray", ylab="Tan suat", xlab="Toc do phim")
}
\end{alltt}
\end{mdframed}
để thu được biểu đồ tần suất như trong Hình~\ref{Fig:Proportional} sau.
\begin{figure}[h]\caption{Biểu đồ cột về số nhược điểm trên tấm gốm} \label{Fig:Proportional}
    \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{Images/Proportional.png}
    \end{center}
\end{figure}

\item Vẽ biểu đồ tần suất tích lũy của số lượng lỗi trên 30 tấm gốm: Trong R ta thực hiện
\begin{mdframed}[hidealllines=true,backgroundcolor=magenta!10]
\begin{alltt}
\textit{
> library(mistat)
> data("BLEMISHES")
> X <- factor(BLEMISHES\$count,levels=0:5)
> X <- prop.table(X) 
> barplot(cumsum(X), main="Tần suất tích lũy của số lượng lỗi trên các tấm gốm",
xlab="Số lỗi", ylab="Tần suất tích lũy")
}
\end{alltt}
\end{mdframed}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

My images don't exist at the place it's supposed to be. As you see at the lines 465. I don't know why the image suddenly jump down to the beneath, please help me!

Comment: You have put the images in a figure environment, the main point of that environment is that it is a _floating_ environment that allows latex to move the content to help with page breaking. that is why figures have numbered captions, so that you can refer to them from the main text before the system has decided where to put them.

Comment: you have posted  a very large document but no one can use it to see the problem, it would have been better to make a _much_ smaller package without all the irrelevant  text and packages loaded and just using `\rule{2cm}{1cm}`  as a black rectangle rather than `\includegraphics` so it did not depend on images that we don't have.

Comment: Honestly i'm very new to LaTex. I can't understand clearly your advice. Please give me a easy to understand solution. My deadline is coming :(

Comment: I can't give you a solution as I have no idea where your figures are going as you have not posted any usable example, sorry. If you need help quickly then you need to make it possible for people to help. If you just want to make figures not move then load the `float` package and use `\begin{figure}[H]` (you have commented out references to that)

Comment: Thank you very much!!! It finally works ^^ I'm sorry for being so inadvertently as this is the first time i post a question to stackexchange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to make figures not move then load the `float` package and use

```
\begin{figure}[H]
```